# Cypher Query with multiple MATCH statements and returns a COLLECT array

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am having trouble with a particular cypher query and I am hoping someone can help. I am trying to query different relationship types of a parent so that I can return a response that includes some key/value pairs for id, name, and node label of the parent while also returning an array of children as another key/value pair in the same object returned. The array of children come from the second relationship MATCH set. When I run this, I am getting an amount of elements in that array that is much larger that the relationship with the parent supports (about 100 elements instead of the intended three).

```
MATCH (n)-[relone:RELATIONSHIP_ONE]->(children_one),
      (n)-[reltwo:RELATIONSHIP_TWO]->(children_two)
WHERE n.id='839930493049039430'
RETURN n.id          AS id,
       n.name        AS name,
       labels(n)[0]  AS type,
       {
         keystring: {
           id: (n.id + '_all'),
           count: count(relone)
         }
       } AS rel_one_representation,
       COLLECT({ 
          name        : children_two.name
       }) AS rel_two_representation
```

Here is the json output I hope to eventually produce:

```
{
    "id"                        : "839930493049039430",
    "name"                      : "lorem",
    "type"                      : "epsim",
    "rel_one_representation"    : {
        "keystring"             : { 
            "id"                : "839930493049039430_all",
            "count"             : 7
        }
    },
    "rel_two_representation"    : [
        {
            "name"              : "barker"
        },
        {
            "name"              : "bird"
        },
        {
            "name"              : "tiki"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you in advance for any guidance you can suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with your query was it was returning results for **all possible pairs** of `children_one` and `children_two` nodes. That caused each `children_two` node to be repeated N1 times, where N1 is the number of `children_one` nodes. It also caused each `children_one` node to be repeated N2 times, where N2 is the number of `children_two` nodes.

## Solution 1:

*This approach uses `WITH` to separate the two `MATCH` clauses to avoid the "pairing effect".*

```
MATCH (n)-[relone:RELATIONSHIP_ONE]->(children_one)
WHERE n.id='839930493049039430'
WITH n, COUNT(relone) AS cnt
MATCH (n)-[reltwo:RELATIONSHIP_TWO]->(children_two)
RETURN n.id AS id, n.name AS name, LABELS(n)[0] AS type, { keystring: { id: (n.id + '_all'), count: cnt }} AS rel_one_representation, COLLECT({ name : children_two.name }) AS rel_two_representation
```

## Solution 2:

*This approach uses the `DISTINCT` keyword to filter out duplicates.*

```
MATCH (n)-[relone:RELATIONSHIP_ONE]->(children_one),(n)-[reltwo:RELATIONSHIP_TWO]->(children_two)
WHERE n.id='839930493049039430'
RETURN n.id AS id, n.name AS name, LABELS(n)[0] AS type, { keystring: { id: (n.id + '_all'), count: COUNT(DISTINCT relone)}} AS rel_one_representation, COLLECT(DISTINCT { name: children_two.name }) AS rel_two_representation
```

Comment: I am new to cypher. Can you please confirm if this approach has any disadvantage over multiple matches: 
MATCH (children_two)<-[reltwo:RELATIONSHIP_TWO]-(n)-[relone:RELATIONSHIP_ONE]->(children_one)
WHERE n.id='839930493049039430'

Comment: @dev You should always use [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/query-profile/) (or EXPLAIN) to compare the execution plans of alternate queries.